# Pascal to C# datatypes

Tags: c#, types, pascal

I have a dll in C#.NET which I am calling to from a Free Pascal application.

Free Pascal code:

```pascal
program DllTester;
procedure PrintIt(age: int32);
    external 'project1';
begin
    PrintIt(4);
    ReadLn();
end.
```

C#.NET code:

```
public static void PrintIt(int age)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Age: {0}", age);
}
```

Now, when I do this, I get this as result:

> Age: 2147344384

When I try to pass a string instead of an integer I don't even get anything, it'd just display:

> Age:

Could anyone help me? Much appreciated!

---EDIT---
To be complete: I edited the IL code so I was able to call the method from Pascal.
This post helped me do that: http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/03/exporting-managed-code-as-unmanaged
Also, when I'm talking about passing the string instead of an int, I obviously changed the datatypes in both projects. I'm using the datatype 'ansistring' for Pascal, whilst I'm using 'string' for C#.

Comment: Can you show, how you execute this function and what pass as parameter?

Comment: Your PrintIt procedure  only accepts **int** as input parameter, not **string**. The difference with Pascal is that, most of the conversions in C# are not implicit. Normally, passing a string in function call should have raised a compile error.

Comment: First of all you should take care of **calling convention**, second... **how do you export a C# function**? C# has not ability to export a C function you can import with an unmanaged language. To do it you have to use some external tool/library. Please add more relevant information.

Comment: Highlight from prev comment: how do you export (in C#) an unmanaged callable function? It's not something natively supported.

Comment: Edited my post, sorry for being a bit unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution!
I had to add the stdcall keyword to make this work.
The Pascal-code now (notice the stdcall;):

```
program DllTester;

procedure PrintIt(message : string); stdcall; external 'project1';

begin
  PrintIt('Hello World');
  ReadLn();
end.
```

Comment: That shouldn't work.  You have to pass the string as PAnsiChar for the default marshalling to work.

Answer (score 1):

To pass complex values between process you should use Windows (read: C) types. F.e. "string" is just pointer to a char, "wide string" is a pointer to Unicode char, and so on.

So when "integer" is a primitive type, you can use it without any additional actions. But "string" is not so primitive.

You can try declare your method with `IntPtr` parameter, and then use [Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7b620dhe(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
void PrintIt(IntPtr s)
{
    var ms = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(s);
    Console.WriteLine(ms);
}
```

Home this helps.

**Remark:** Calling managed code from unmanaged is not good idea. You can try use classic tools to inter-process communication like memory mapped files, pipes. You can publish you C# classes as COM-object and use them directly from FreePascal also.

Comment: I regret to say your solution doesn't work :(
I'm aware of the fact that this isn't a good idea, but my employeer (I'm a student employee) wants me to create a .NET DLL he can access from Delphi.

Anyhow, I'll try publishing my C# classes as COM-objects. Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: What are symptoms? To compile this C# code you should enable "unsafe" instructions. Can you debug your C# code? As far as I remember, Visual Studio can display bytes at the address of `IntPtr`, so if you can set breakpoint at `PstrToStringAnsi`, then you can check the value of the input parameter `s`.

Comment: How would I debug using visual studio when I'm calling the DLL from Pascal?

Comment: Visual Studio debugger can be "attached to process". F.e. you can such way debug SharePoint extensions. As I can understand you start .NET host inside your Pascal application?